# PowerShell Get-ChildItem invoke in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-4.0

I have this below powershell script to converted into a C#.

```
$file = $solution.DisplayName.substring(0, $solution.DisplayName.Length - 4) + ".dll"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly" -Filter $file -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
```

I have tried this one but could not succeed.

```
        string dllName = "MyOwn.dll";
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddCommand("Get-ChildItem");
        ps.AddParameter(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly");
        ScriptBlock filter = ScriptBlock.Create(dllName);
        ps.AddParameter("-Filter", filter);
        foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "{0,-24}{1}",
                result.Members["Length"].Value,
                result.Members["Name"].Value);
        }
```

Also Is there any equivalent of Get-ChildItem in C# ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a rather old question, but as it is unanswered and is related to [a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39832737/579895) I have just answered, I thought i could resolve this also. The way I found it works to exec a "Get-ChildItem" is, instead of using `PowerShell.Create()` is using `RunspaceInvoke` and just throw the command as is. Below is how it would work for this case:

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoke = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
       Collection<PSObject> result = invoke.Invoke("Get-ChildItem \"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\" -Filter \"Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.Interop.dll\" -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo");
}
```